# Globally disable Ext JS Animations

Tags: javascript, ipad, extjs

I'm testing an intranet web app in an iPad but the animations to open "windows" and show message boxes are horribly slow.

I've tried setting the global Ext.enableFx to false, and confirmed that flag is still false after page load in Firebug.  The animations are still occurring though so I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you show a window, the second (optional) argument to `show()` is the target to animate from.  Omit that and you should not get the animation.

**EDIT:**

Not tested, but glancing at the `Window` code you should be able to do this (put it after your Ext includes and before your app code):

```
Ext.override(Ext.Window, {
    animShow: function(){
        this.afterShow();
    },
    animHide: function(){
       this.el.hide();
       this.afterHide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, I figured I might be able to do that.  What I was trying to avoid was going through and modifying code with animations individually.  Do you think its feasible that I could override some framework methods to stop the animations at a global level?  I will take a look at the source in question tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: That override handles most of it.  Thanks!